# Jquery animate(): storing css key/value pairs

Tags: jquery

If I have something like

```
$('#element').animate({'top':'-140px'},2000);
```

Is it possible to pre-define a bunch of key/value pairs somehow, so I can then just use

```
 $('#element').animate(firstPos,2000).animate(secondPos,2000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var firstPos = {key : object}; var secondPos = {key : value}`?

Comment: If your target browsers support CSS3 keyframes, they do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Steve- I don't think keyframes are suitable, as this is actually part of a much larger operation...

Comment: @Inigo I don't think i understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Fyb8/

```
var firstPos= {'top':'40px'};
var secondPos= {'top':'80px'};
$('#element').animate(firstPos,2000).animate(secondPos,2000);
```

Comment: It works- great, thanks. I tried this but hadn't realised there was another error on my page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You can define an object literal like

```
firstPos = {
  top: '-140px'
};

secondPos = {
  top: '0px'
};
```

and then pass that into your animate() call. However, you probably do not want to chain your animate calls but rather fire off the secondPos animation after the first one finishes. So you would want to perform the second animation inside the callback for the first, like:

```
$("#element").animate(firstPos, 2000, function() { $(this).animate(secondPos, 2000); })
```

May also want to read up on [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)